# Regular expression for string followed by arguments in parenthesis

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for the following scenario.

It could be simple alphanumeric string (It can have '@' even if it is special character) or alphanumeric string followed by argument list in parenthesis or alphanumeric string followed by blank parenthesis:

1. My_macro -> accept this
2. My_macro() -> accept this
3. My_macro(arg1, arg2, arg3) -> accept this

I am new to regular expression, I read some tutorials and could form this regular expression.

```
([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_@]*) | ([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+[\(][a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_@,]+[\)])
```

This isn't working.

Comment: Depending on the language this is being interpreted/executed in, you might have case-sensitivity options. It might help clean this up a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[\w@]+(\((\w+,?\s*)*\))?$
```

matches:

```
My_macro(arg1,  arg2, arg3)
My_macro(arg1)
My_macro
My_macro()
My_macro@()

^                   # Line Start
[\w@]+              # Matches alphanumerics and @ => My_@macro
(\((\w+,?\s*)*\))?  # Matches optional argument (empty) list (), (arg) and (arg1, arg2) 
$                   # Matches Line End
```

The question is what exactly are you trying to achieve. Why do you need to match these strings? Your requirements matches most strings anyways.

Comment: Your example also matches 0123 (0123 0123), I think.

Answer (score 2):

Some things I notice:

- the first part (macro name) will be present in all cases, so you don't need to repeat it. (You can use "?" for optional parts--the parens and args list.)
- the `+` after the `[a-zA-Z]` expression is redundant with the `*` following the `[a-zA-Z...]` expression.
- you may/may not have extra spaces around the pipe/bar ("|"). This might be messing up your regex.
- Your examples have spaces between the args, but your regex doesn't.

[Update]
One more tidbit:

- the comma is tricky. You'll basically need something like this: (pardon my pseudo-regex)

  (<arg expression> ([spaces]*[comma][spaces]*<arg expression>)* )?

... which should optionally match everything inside the parens.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Za-z@][A-Za-z0-9@]*\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z@][A-Za-z0-9@]*\s*(\s*,\s*[A-Za-z@][A-Za-z0-9@]*\s*)+)?\s*\)
```

Btw, I would not do this with a single regular expression, but first get the identifier, then strip the parantheses, and then split the argument list. In code.

Answer (score 0):

in php it looks like:

```
    $subject = "My_macro My_@acro My_macro() My_macro(arg1, arg2, arg3)";
    $pattern = '![a-zA-Z0-9_@]+(\((([a-zA-Z0-9_@]+(\,\s)?){3})?\))?!';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);


Array
(
    [0] => My_macro
    [1] => My_@acro
    [2] => My_macro()
    [3] => My_macro(arg1, arg2, arg3)
)
```